# How to install window decorations from file?

Tags: kubuntu, customization

I got some window decorations from KDE-look.org and I went into settings to change it but it doesn't give me the option to install decorations from file. How do I do so, if it's even possible?

Comment: Are you using Kwin, Compiz, What? IIRC they go into the hidden .kde folder in your home directory.

Comment: @UriHerrera I'm using what ever the default is for Kubuntu 11.10 with KDE 4.8.1 is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:**

> the option to install decorations from file. How do I do so, if it's
>   even possible?

**A:**

It depends ;)

**Engine + decoration files**

Example #1- Aurorae - engine included

The Aurorae decoration engine is part of the KDE.

GHNS: 
System Settings > Workspace Apperance > Window Decorations > Get New Decorations

Manual from a file:
Unpack the theme to the ~/.kde/share/apps/aurorae/themes/

Example #2- deKorator - external engine

Package: kwin-style-dekorator

```
Description: Windows decoration engine for KDE 4 using user-supplied PNG files
 With deKorator, easily create your own window decoration for KDE 4!
 deKorator uses your own made images for buttons, borders and so on.
 Go ahead and be creative!
 An example called uglyTheme is provided to show its possibilities.
 .
 Themes can be created by the user with the help of a drawing program or can be
 downloaded from http://www.kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=21
 .
 This is a windows decoration engine, not a style.
Homepage: http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/deKorator?content=87921
```

After the installation of the engine: System Settings > Workspace Apperance > Window Decorations > deKorator

The deKorator has an option to install the theme from a file.

[image]